# Suffix array construction in \$ O(n \log^2 n) \$

Tags: python, strings

Here is my implementation of the suffix array construction algorithm which follows [this paper](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/suffix-array.pdf) (specifically, pages 4 and 6).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from math import ceil, log2


def sufar(txt):

    txt = txt + chr(0)
    N, tokens = len(txt), sorted(set(t for t in txt))

    equivalence = {t: i for i, t in enumerate(tokens)}

    c, r = [equivalence[t] for t in txt], [(0, 0, 0)]

    for i in range(1, ceil(log2(N)) + 1):
        n = 2 ** (i - 1)

        r = sorted([(c[j],  c[(j + n) % N], j) for j in range(N)])

        c[r[0][2]] = 0
        for j in range(1, N):
            c[r[j][2]] = c[r[j - 1][2]]
            if r[j][0:2] != r[j - 1][0:2]:
                c[r[j][2]] += 1

    return [result[2] for result in r][1:]
```

This implementation looks correct, here are [the unit tests](https://github.com/all3fox/algos/blob/master/sufar_test.py) I have tried.

My concerns are:

1. `txt = txt + chr(0)` to add a special symbol `$` which is not supposed to be in `txt`.
2. using `if r[j][0:2] != r[j - 1][0:2]` to understand if the suffixes at positions `j` and `j - 1` are from the same equivalence class. I would expect the comparison to be `if r[j][0:1] != r[j - 1][0:1]` but that fails the unit tests.

Comment: Are you experiencing an error, or unexpected/undesirable behaviour? If you are, you should head over to stackoverflow.com. A rule of thumb is that stackoverflow likes broken code, and codereview likes working code.

Comment: as far as I can tell this code works. It passes the unittests I created and linked to. This code is not known to be broken but it might be, of course

Comment: "but that fails the unit tests" this drew my attention. I didn't read the rest, but generally whenever I see "fails" I imagine the code fails the developers expectations. I apologise. I shall read your code and see if there's anything I can do.

Comment: I've to admit, I'm fuzzy about what the algorithm does, but following your code, here are some things that seem strange: you initialize `r`, but then you don't use the initial value (you could use `for ...: else` if you wanted to do something when the loop isn't entered). Also: `sorted([...])` is the same as `sorted(...)` (you could drop the square brackets). Also, why so economic variable names? It's OK for an iterator variable's name to be short, but I can't figure what `r` stands for.

Comment: you are mistaken about `for ...: else` --- the `else` clause is executed when the [loop finishes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for). Otherwise, I am updating the question with a bit more readable code. Econoic variable names so that it is quicker to type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Review

I'm reviewing the updated version of the code only.

1. There's no docstring. What does this function do? How do I call it? What does it return? Can you give an example of what it does?
2. The names are obscure. We're not running out of letters, so `suffix_array` would be clearer to the reader than `sufar`. (You said in comments that this was to make it "quicker to type" but in that case maybe you need a better editor? Most programming editors these days have some kind of completion facility on names.)
3. The algorithm is tricky enough that it needs explanation. My advice would be to add comments to the loop explaining the invariants that holds at each iteration. (Figuring out loop invariants is invaluable for understand how an algorithm works, and they can be turned into assertions that check the correctness of the implementation.)
4. The code does not actually implement the algorithm in the Vladu/Negruşeri paper. A comparison with their C implementation on page 6 shows that there are two points of difference.

   (i) When preparing the `L` array (`result` in `sufar`), if `i + cnt` is out of bounds (`j + n` in `sufar`), the dummy element is used, but in `sufar` the index is wrapped around to get `cls[(j + n) % N]`.

   (ii) When computing the new `P` array (`cls` in `sufar`), if `L[i]` differs from `L[i - 1]` then the entry in `P` is assigned the value `i`. However, in `sufar`, the entry in `cls` is assigned the value `cls[result[j - 1][2]] + 1`.

   Nonetheless, despite these differences in the implementation, `sufar` gets the correct result!

   In case (i) that's because the original algorithm imagines extending the string with enough dummy characters to make the suffixes the same length (thus `abac` becomes `abac$$$$` and the 4-character suffixes are `abac`, `bac$`, `ac$$`, `c$$$`, and `$$$$` which gets discarded), whereas `sufar` images extending the string with a single dummy character and then a repeat of itself (thus `abac` becomes `abac$aba` and the 4-character suffixes are  `abac`, `bac$`, `ac$a`, `c$ab` and `$aba` which gets discarded). But the single `$` is enough for these to come out in the correct order.

   In case (ii) we only care about the sorted order of the entries in `P`, not their actual values, so the change makes no difference.

   I think that difference (ii) is fine, but (i) is sufficiently tricky that I would avoid it if at all possible. (Or else write a comment explaining why I did it.)
5. To make it easy for the reader to check that you've correctly implemented the algorithm in the paper, I would use the same notation as the paper unless there was a very good reason not to. So `txt` → `A`, `cls` → `P`, `result` → `L`, `N` → `n`, `n` → `count`, etc.
6. Instead of `set(t for t in txt)`, just write `set(txt)`.
7. Instead of adding `chr(0)` to `txt` and then making equivalence classes for the entries in `txt` (which relies on `chr(0)` not already appearing in `txt`), make the equivalence class *first*, and then append an equivalence class that you know is not present, for example `-1`.
8. Instead of computing `ceil(log2(N))`, start with `count = 1` and double it each iteration until it is too large. This avoids the dependence on the `math` module.
9. It turns out that there's no need to actually add a dummy value to the text in the first place. If we avoid this, then we can also avoid adding 1 to `N` and avoid having to drop the initial element of `result` at the end.
10. The initialization of the `cls` array based on the sorted equivalence classes of the length-1 substrings of `txt` is really just a special case of the way that `cls` is updated in the loop. If the loop were turned upside down so that it computes `cls` first and then `result`, you could arrange to avoid the special initialization of `cls`. See below for how this is done.
11. Another benefit of turning the loop upside down is that it avoids a wasteful computation of `cls` on the last iteration that will never be used.
12. Numeric tuple lookups like the `[2]` in `result[j][2]` are hard to understand. It's usually better to *unpack* the tuple into local variables so that you can refer to its elements by name.
13. In Python it's usually best to avoid iterating over sequence indices, if possible, and to prefer iterating over the elements directly. Here the computation of `cls` involves iterating over pairs of adjacent elements in `result`; you could use the [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from the `itertools` module, or combine [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) as I've done below.

#### 2. Revised code

```
from itertools import chain, islice

def suffix_array(A):
    """Return a list of the starting positions of the suffixes of the
    sequence A in sorted order.

    For example, the suffixes of ABAC, in sorted order, are ABAC, AC,
    BAC and C, starting at positions 0, 2, 1, and 3 respectively:

    >>> suffix_array('ABAC')
    [0, 2, 1, 3]

    """
    # This implements the algorithm of Vladu and Negruşeri; see
    # http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/suffix-array.pdf

    L = sorted((a, i) for i, a in enumerate(A))
    n = len(A)
    count = 1
    while count < n:
        # Invariant: L is now a list of pairs such that L[i][1] is the
        # starting position in A of the i'th substring of length
        # 'count' in sorted order. (Where we imagine A to be extended
        # with dummy elements as necessary.)

        P = [0] * n
        for (r, i), (s, j) in zip(L, islice(L, 1, None)):
            P[j] = P[i] + (r != s)

        # Invariant: P[i] is now the position of A[i:i+count] in the
        # sorted list of unique substrings of A of length 'count'.

        L = sorted(chain((((P[i],  P[i+count]), i) for i in range(n - count)),
                         (((P[i], -1), i) for i in range(n - count, n))))
        count *= 2
    return [i for _, i in L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

For appending the 'chr(0)', it would be easier to do an in-place append, `txt += chr(0)`.

You shouldn't need to do `set(t for t in txt)`, just `set(txt)` should work for most types.

This may be my personal issue, but I think putting two variable declerations on one line, such as `N, tokens = len(txt), sorted(set(t for t in txt))`, is bad style.

For `i`, you start the range at `1`, then immediately subtract `1` from it.  Better to just start at `0`.

It might be a little clearer to get the `n` values up-front and then iterate over those.

You overwrite `result` each instance of the loop, so there is no need to declare it up-front.

Rather than using a list comprehension in the last line, you can just zip it.

Your `c[(j + n) % N]` is just the values of `c` rolled `n` to the left, which can be done by slicing for lists: `c[n:]+c[:n]`.

However, since you only ever use the last elements of each tuple in `result`, it would be easier to split it into three lists, one for the indexes, another for `cls`, and another for rolled `cls`.

You also don't need to do the full calculation on the last loop, since you don't use any of the changes after the `sorted`.

```
from math import ceil, log2


def sufar_3(txt):
    if not txt:
        return []
    txt += chr(0)
    N = len(txt)

    equivalence = {t: i for i, t in enumerate(sorted(set(txt)))}
    cls = [equivalence[t] for t in txt]

    ns = [(2**i)%N for i in range(ceil(log2(N)))]
    for n in ns[:-1]:
        result = sorted(zip(cls, cls[n:]+cls[:n], range(N)))
        result0, result1, inds = list(zip(*result))

        cls[inds[0]] = 0
        for j in range(1, N):
            cls[inds[j]] = cls[inds[j-1]]
            if (result0[j], result1[j]) != (result0[j-1], result1[j-1]):
                cls[inds[j]] += 1

    n = ns[-1]
    result = sorted(zip(cls, cls[n:]+cls[:n], range(N)))

    return list(list(zip(*result))[2][1:])
```

However, you can simplify this further by using `numpy`.  Each cycle, you can roll `cls` the correct amount and then use `lexsort` to sort just the original and rolled `cls`.  This will give you the indexes.

It appears the final for loop amounts to a cumulative sum on whether the current elements of `cls` and the current elements of the rotated `cls` are different than the previous ones (with `False` being a value of `0` and `True` being a value of `1`).  You can check whether elements are different based on their `diff`, which you can then convert to `bool` and do a logical `or` on.  Then you can just do a `cumsum` on that, since that will automatically coerce to integers.

So I think that your algorithm will end up like this with `numpy`:

```
from math import ceil, log2
import numpy as np


def sufar_np(txt):
    if not txt:
        return []
    txt += chr(0)

    equivalence = {t: i for i, t in enumerate(sorted(set(txt)))}
    cls = np.array([equivalence[t] for t in txt])
    ns = 2**np.arange(ceil(log2(len(txt))))

    for n in ns[:-1]:
        cls1 = np.roll(cls, -n)
        inds = np.lexsort((cls1, cls))
        result = np.logical_or(np.diff(cls[inds]), 
                               np.diff(cls1[inds]))

        cls[inds[0]] = 0
        cls[inds[1:]] = np.cumsum(result)

    cls1 = np.roll(cls, ns[-1])
    return np.lexsort((cls1, cls))[1:].tolist()
```

Comment: The numpy code is very good. When benchmarking it runs about ten times faster than the code in Gareth Rees answer.